# LinkedIn apply ats error

Tags: linkedin-api

I have an app on LinkedIn.
On the javascript SKD panel the url of my site is OK.
I want to use the "apply" button on the site.

Here is my code

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.linkedin.com/mjobs/awli/awliWidget">
</script>
<script type="IN/AwliWidget"  
  data-company-job-code="<?php echo get_field('reference'); ?>" 
  data-company-token=""       
  data-mode="BUTTON_DATA" 
  data-callback-method="onProfileData" 
  data-api-key="86ta6q3gvq3es3"
  data-allow-sign-in="true">
</script>
```

When I get the page :

Uncaught Error: Error trying to initialize the widget! Error is :atsIntegration: error.ats.integration.not.valid

The question is what is "ats" (some sort of key ?) and how to get one ?

Thank !